# Creating RSS from Javascript formatted data

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, rss, weather

I have a JavaScript that pulls data from a Weather API that I need to get into an RSS file so it can be read by two broadcast devices.

```
const api_url = 'API-URL-&-KEY';
let firstTime = true;
async function getWeather(direction) {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const { temperature, humidity, feelsLike, windSpeed, windDirection, rainDaily } = data;
  var direction = getWindDirection(data.observation.windDirection);
  var FullWind = ' ' + direction + ' ' + data.observation.windSpeed + ' MPH ';
  if(data.observation.windSpeed > 3){
    document.getElementById('WindS').textContent = FullWind;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('WindS').textContent = 'CALM';
  }
  document.getElementById('TempF').textContent = data.observation.temperature;
  document.getElementById('TempL').textContent = data.observation.feelsLike;
  document.getElementById('Humdi').textContent = data.observation.humidity;
  document.getElementById('RainD').textContent = data.observation.rainDaily;
  document.getElementById('DewPt').textContent = data.observation.dewPoint;
  document.getElementById('Press').textContent = data.observation.pressureSeaLevel;
  document.getElementById('TimeD').textContent = data.observation.observationTimeAdjustedLocalStr;
}
function getWindDirection(direction) {
    var wndDir = "N";
    if (((direction >= 349) && (direction <= 359)) || ((direction >= 0) && (direction <= 11))) {
        wndDir = "N";
    } else if ((direction >= 12) && (direction <= 34)) {
        wndDir = "NNE";
    } else if ((direction >= 35) && (direction <= 56)) {
        wndDir = "NE";
    } else if ((direction >= 57) && (direction <= 78)) {
        wndDir = "ENE";
    } else if ((direction >= 79) && (direction <= 101)) {
        wndDir = "E";
    } else if ((direction >= 102) && (direction <= 123)) {
        wndDir = "ESE";
    } else if ((direction >= 124) && (direction <= 146)) {
        wndDir = "SE";
    } else if ((direction >= 147) && (direction <= 168)) {
        wndDir = "SSE";
    } else if ((direction >= 169) && (direction <= 191)) {
        wndDir = "S";
    } else if ((direction >= 192) && (direction <= 213)) {
        wndDir = "SSW";
    } else if ((direction >= 214) && (direction <= 236)) {
        wndDir = "SW";
    } else if ((direction >= 237) && (direction <= 258)) {
        wndDir = "WSW";
    } else if ((direction >= 259) && (direction <= 281)) {
        wndDir = "W";
    } else if ((direction >= 282) && (direction <= 303)) {
        wndDir = "WNW";
    } else if ((direction >= 304) && (direction <= 326)) {
        wndDir = "NW";
    } else if ((direction >= 327) && (direction <= 348)) {
        wndDir = "NNW";
    }
    return wndDir;
}
getWeather();
setInterval(getWeather, 10000);
```

For testing the data I have a simple site for verification:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title"Weather RSS" herf="rss.xml"/>
    <title>Weather for HS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pull.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Temp: <span id="TempF"></span>F<br />
      Wind: <span id="WindS"></span><br />
      Humidity: <span id="Humdi"></span>%<br />
      Feels Like: <span id="TempL"></span>F<br />
      Rain: <span id="RainD"></span> INCH<br />
      Pressure: <span id="Press"></span>"<br />
      Dew Point: <span id="DewPt"></span>F<br />
      Pull at: <span id="TimeD"></span><br />
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the PHP side I have this:

```
<?php
$web_url = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$date = date('r');
$str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
$str .= "<rss version='2.0'>";
    $str .= "<channel>";
        $str .= "<title>HS Weather</title>";
        $str .= "<description>Weather Pull</description>";
        $str .= "<language>en-US</language>";
        $str .= "<link>$web_url</link>";
        $str .= "<pubDate>$date</pubDate>";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "classicmodels");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productCode DESC");
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Temp: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . " F</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Wind: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Humidity: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "%</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Feels like: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "F</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Rain: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "INCH</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Pressure: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "\"</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
            $str .= "<item>";
                $str .= "<title>Dew Point: " . htmlspecialchars($elm) . "F</title>";
            $str .= "</item>";
    $str .= "</channel>";
$str .= "</rss>";
file_put_contents("rss.xml", $str);
?>
```

htmlspecialchars($elm) is currently a placeholder for the weather data.

I have been finding it hard to pass the JavaScript variables over to the PHP code and I'm trying to figure out a simpler way of going from my sorted data right to the RSS file.

Since I have a NAS and Raspberry Pi that can both run NodeJS I'm wondering if I can have NodeJS run the JavaScript and have said script create a RSS or XML file every 5 seconds to the device.

From that I can do a simple network share and I have my needed data.

Comment: Why don't you just use php to call the API??

Comment: The commenter saying you can use PHP to make the API request is correct. PHP can make API requests--on the server side. Your web page includes `pull.js` to do this--in the browser. The server won't see what comes from the API call unless you were to post the response from the browser to the server; which is not necessary. Look into using PHP's `curl` functions or the `Requests` library to call the API from PHP. If the API can return JSON, you can parse the JSON with `json_decode`, otherwise you'll need to parse the HTML with PHP's `simplexml` or DOM functions.